# Kotlin: Where should the top level functions go?

Tags: coding-style, kotlin

Is there a best practice / convention as to where the top level functions should go in Kotlin?

Say I'm creating a package `myproject.util` with utility functions. In Java, it's a good practice to create a directory structure matching the package structure. Not sure if that's actually true for Kotlin. Anyway, I guess the utility functions should go to `myproject/util/somefile.kt`, but I'm not sure what the `somefile` should be.

Comment: You can see some organization in this library of functions: https://github.com/kohesive/klutter/tree/master/core-jdk6/src/main/kotlin/uy/klutter/core (look at folders below and groupings in files)

Comment: Thanks! I quite like the pattern used in the `core.common` package where the top-level functions with no relation to any particular class are in `core/common/Common.kt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement to put all the utility functions into one file. You can create multiple files for top-level functions and name each of them according to what the functions in each file do.

If you have just a handful of functions and don't want to invent any new names, the easiest option is to name the file the same as the package (`util.kt` in your example).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about `myproject/util.kt`, but then sub-packages are a problem. I can definitely see that there are various ways of solving it. I was mainly wondering if there's a commonly used convention.